# Python if statement "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, syntax-error

Trying to execute someone's code, getting a syntax error. No idea why :(

```
def GetParsers( self, systags ):
    childparsers = reduce( lambda a,b : a+b, [[]] + [ plugin.GetParsers( systags ) for plugin in self.plugins ] )
    parsers = [ p for plist in [ self.parsers[t] for t in systags if self.parsers.has_key(t) ] for p in plist ]
    return reduce( lambda a,b : ( a+[b] if not b in a else a ), [[]] + parsers + childparsers )
```

And the error is

```
File "base.py", line 100
    return reduce( lambda a,b : ( a+[b] if not b in a else a ), [[]] + parsers + childparsers )
```

Python Version

```
Python 2.2.3 (#1, May  1 2006, 12:33:49)
[GCC 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-54)] on linux2

                                         ^
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace and python version? It parses correctly here.

Comment: Doesn't give me a syntax error. What version of python are you running? What version fo python are they running?

Comment: Works fine for me in both 3.1 and 2.6

Comment: Python 2.2.3 (#1, May  1 2006, 12:33:49)
[GCC 3.2.3 20030502 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-54)] on linux2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional expressions were added in 2.5 [(source)](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions) - you have 2.2. So no conditional expressions for you, I fear. They just don't exist yet in that version. Definitively update (not only for this little change, there are literally thousands of them since '06) if you can.

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade your Python installation to at least 2.5. [More Information](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to a newer version of Python will be the best solution, but if for some reason you can't upgrade you could update the code to use [the and-or trick](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html#d0e9975).

So this:

```
>>> 'a' if 1 == 2 else 'b'
'b'
```

Becomes:

```
>>> (1 == 2) and 'a' or 'b'
'b'
```

There is a slight problem here in that if the value you're return for True itself evaluates to False this statement won't work as you want.  You can work around this as follows:

```
>>> ((1 == 2) and ['a'] or ['b'])[0]
'b'
```

In this case because the value is a non-empty list it will never evaluate to False so the trick will always work.